# Java 1.4.2 memory analysis tools

Tags: java, memory-leaks, weblogic

We have an application running on Weblogic 8.1.3, using the bundled 1.4.2 JDK, and it's leaking memory moderately rapidly.

I've done some reading around about how to fix memory leaks, but most of it seems to assume that the JDK being used is 5 or higher. Are there any tools available for earlier versions?

Other than that, there's very little information that we've found: the leak only seems to occur on the full production environment, rather than the test environments.

- We have two machines running weblogic, clustered for load balancing
- The leak occurs on *one* of the clustered servers at a time (?!), but never both
- The leak sometimes, but not always, switches from server to server when Weblogic is restarted.

So I figure that there must be an object created at server startup that can be created on one (but not both) servers that is behind the leak. Does this seem a reasonable place to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) supports profiling Java 1.4 in its current version (7.0)

You could have a look at [this screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/04/in-screencast-below-i-show-strategy-for.html) on how to search for memory leaks with JProfiler.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Comment: Sweet. Well, I've grabbed the trial version, and so far it seems to be connecting and profiling as expected. I am experiencing a few issues with some connections to our SonicMQ server, but aside from that, it looks like we might be onto a winner...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to run `jvisualvm` and look into the memory used (heap dump)?

-> http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html

Comment: Yep, sadly. I can get it to connect to the JVM, but the memory analysis section requires the target to be running on JDK 6 or 7. We can see the heap usage, but no more than that.

Comment: jvisualvm uses jstatd and not JVMTI, so it will simply not recognize the JVM of version 1.4.